# Use Paste special in excel macro while copying multiple workbooks in one master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a macro to copy multiple workbooks into one integrated workbook. I am able to do it; however I am not finding a way to use paste special to kee the formatting of source worksheets intact. I would really appreciate if someone could please help/guide

here is the code:

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\ssehgal\Documents\Excel-Files-For-Macro\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What formatting gets lost? Copying the whole sheet normally keeps all the formats intact.

Comment: @ChipsLetten  Formatting like the header color gets chaged

Comment: Gets changed? So it goes from yellow to blue for example? That sounds like you need to copy the Theme from the source workbook as well as the sheets. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17911701/4243498)